# accessing data on encrypted drive

Tags: boot, encryption, data-recovery

Please be patient with me as I am still learning how to do anything Linux, starting with Ubuntu.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and had some issues playing around with it and petty much now it won't boot up which would be fine as I am using the computer to play with Ubuntu nothing more. But while on holidays, I had copied some family pics on the hard drive I moved there to watch on TV though HDMI, and my camera has since been stolen. so I want to try save the family pics \ vids which fortunately are on the Ubuntu drive... which I can't access.

But there is more... When I first installed Ubuntu... I selected to encrypt the drive. I do have the password. so that is not an issue. issue is I have tried to access the drive by booting up off an Ubuntu 15.10 I think.

SO I figured I will see the drive, be prompted for password and then I can access my data and save to USB drive. But no I don't have permission to access the drive. No request for password.

Help with instructions as I have limited (very Limited) Linux knowledge.

Jinn

Comment: Did you encrypt your entire system drive, or just your home folder? The whole system drive encryption uses LUKS (and probably lvm), while home encryption only uses eCryptFS. When you boot from a 15.10 "live" dvd/usb, can you mount & browse the rest of the files on your old Ubuntu hard drive, and only see the home files as encrypted (long "nonsense" names)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover data from old encrypted hard drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196233/how-to-recover-data-from-old-encrypted-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

***From Live Cd/DVD*** 
 **First ensure the partition containing your encrypted home directory is mounted.**  You can easily mount it by clicking It in the file manager; you will see an eject (unmount) icon, indicating the partition is mounted.

Now Open a Terminal (Ctl  Alt T)

Then look for the drive:

```
 sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
```

**This command will offer to recover an encrypted directory if it locates one.**

**Assuming the command found a wrapped passphrase file on your system, it will prompt you for your login passphrase. If it doesn’t find this file, you’ll need the mount passphrase from the `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` command – hopefully you have a copy of this. If you don’t, you can’t recover your files.**

If you have found the drive and entered the correct password

The command will mount the encrypted directory in your `/tmp` directory.(your temporary files)

You can access this directory to view the decrypted versions of your files. However, **you may not have read access to this directory as the live CD user.**

To access the directory with a graphical file browser, run Nautilus as root. Press Alt+F2, type `gksu nautilus` and press Enter.

You will now be able to access your files from the Nautilus window running as root. From here, you can easily copy the files to an external hard drive or another location!!

[References -UbuntuGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: I tried this as I seen it posted elsewhere. did not help or perhaps i dont understand. i do have password. this is what i get... $ sudo ecryptfs-recover-privateINFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
find: File system loop detected; `/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl' is part of the same file system loop as `/sys/kernel/debug'

Comment: i do find in tem directory 3 locked files which have... This location could not be displayed  you do not have permissions to view the contents of "systemd-private...etc...

Comment: Just login to tty Ctl Alt f1 or f2 type gksu natilus and you should now have access

Comment: I did this ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /media/ubuntu/efce1cdd-542f-4e9e-981b-b7fec59ca8af
INFO: Found [/media/ubuntu/efce1cdd-542f-4e9e-981b-b7fec59ca8af].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: y
INFO: Could not find your wrapped passphrase file.
INFO: To recover this directory, you MUST have your original MOUNT passphrase.
INFO: When you first setup your encrypted private directory, you were told to record
INFO: your MOUNT passphrase.
INFO: It should be 32 characters long, consisting of [0-9] and [a-f].

Enter your MOUNT passphrase: 
INFO: Success!  Private data mounted at

Comment: I go to the temp file where it is located and get the message. this location could not be displayed. you do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of ecryptfs.xyz"

Comment: That's because you are trying to access the files with a different user than you used to copy them to the drive. You will need to change either ownership or permissions on the folder before you can access it as any user other than root.

Comment: @AncientJinn The message *"location could not be displayed. you do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents"* just means that you're not running the file browser (or terminal command) as root. Did you do the last step to run `gksu nautilus`? Or in a terminal, just `sudo ls -la <ecryptfs.xyz>` to list it?

Comment: I have tried gksu nautilus. i keep getting gksu is currently not  install. but when i run sudo apt-get install gksu i get nothing.  tried many combos but nothing... now sudo ls -la opens files so i can see them in terminal.  but not accessible through gui

Comment: I closed all windows etc... and then relaunched Terminal and the gksu nautilus worked. and the password prompt popped up. so I have access to all files and able to reset the permissions thanks. but... I cant access the content on the desktop. "access your private data.desktop file" needs to be mounted I think.

Comment: Great you now have access to your files! Please remember to click the ChecK MarK! If you need more help i would edit your question or create a new one